# Rotate image through Y-axis on web page

Tags: image, transform

What are my options for rotating an image on a web page through the Y-axis? I'm not sure if I even have the terminology right. Is this called a rotate or a transform. Most of the searches that I've done with "rotate image" show images being turned. What I'm looking for is the mirror image of the image or what it looks like if you were standing behind it.

I'm looking for something that might be available as a plugin to jQuery or something that can be done with CSS3 or HTML5. I'm also considering doing this in Silverlight but I'm still trying to find an example of what this on the web...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is, what you seek:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/reflect

Comment: +1 That's very close to what I'm looking for except that it's rotating through the x-axis.

Comment: Don´t you think you could try this with the code from the plugin?
I´d be glad, if you could give an example, so I´m able to understand, how the reflection should look.

Comment: Here's an example page that I setup to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve: http://guyellisrocks.com/examples/flipping_image.htm